# Malicious uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I read some articles about uploading files, people can upload malicious programs (php, exe,...) to attack the server and the website, what is the safest way to protect and avoid any danger for the website and the server, this is a class I am using, if anything to add, please let me know (clamav scanning disabled, it takes time to scan the file):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
</head>

<body>
<?php

final class uploadFiles {

// params
private $uErrors=array(), $aErrors=array(), $dErrors=array();

/*
 # uErrors = Show errors to the user
 # aErrors = Show errors to the admin ONLY
 # dErrors = Send delete file error to admin
 */

// get user group, level and id
public function __construct($fileField) {

    $fileName     = basename($_FILES['fileName']['name']); // get file name

    $this->fileName     = trim($fileName);
    $this->fileField    = $fileField;

    # extract file info

    // get file name before the dot sign
    //$info       = pathinfo($this->fileName);
    //$fileInit   = basename($this->fileName,'.'.$info['extension']);

    $this->fileTmp      = $_FILES[$this->fileField]['tmp_name']; // get temp name
    $this->fileSize     = basename($_FILES[$this->fileField]['size']); // get file size
    $this->fileType     = basename($_FILES[$this->fileField]['type']); // get file type
    $this->fileError    = basename($_FILES[$this->fileField]['error']); // list error codes
    //$this->fileInit     = $fileInit;

    } // end function __construct

// check if file_uploads is set to ON or OFF
public final function checkUploads() {

    if(ini_get('file_uploads')){   
        return true;
        } 
        return false;
} // end checkUploads


// get file extension
public final function getFileExt() {

    $getInfo = pathinfo($this->fileName);
    $fileExt = basename($getInfo['extension']);
    $fileExt = strtolower($fileExt);

    $this->fileExt  = $fileExt;


    return $this->fileExt;
} // end getFileExt


// allowed file extensions
public final function allowedFileExt($extArray=array()) {       

    $this->extArray = $extArray;

    $authExtList    = implode(' ،',$this->extArray);

    $this->authExtList = $authExtList;

    if((in_array($this->getFileExt(), $this->extArray)) && (!empty($this->fileName)))
    {
        return true;
    }
        $this->uErrors[] = 'إمتداد الملف غير مقبول، المرجو إختيار أحد الإمتدادات التالية: '.$this->authExtList;
        return false;
} // end allowedFileExt


// allowed file size
public final function allowedFileSize($maxFileSize) {       

    $this->maxFileSize = $maxFileSize;

    if($this->fileSize > $this->maxFileSize) 
    {
        $this->uErrors[] = 'حجم الملف كبير جدا';
        return false;
    } 
        return true;
} // end allowedFileSize


// create a new folder
public final function newDir($dirname) {

    $this->dirname  = $dirname;

    // check if the directory exists or not
    if(is_dir($this->dirname))
    {
        // if exists, check whether is writable or not
        if(!is_writable($this->dirname)) {
            // NB: You need to have enough permissions to perform this action
            // set proper chmod, DO NOT user umask
            if(chmod($this->dirname, 0755)) { // change the chmod to 755
             return true;
        } else {
            //$this->uErrors[] = 'ليس لديك صلاحيات كافية لتغيير صلاحيات المجلد';
            return false;
        }
        } // end is_writable

        return true;
    } else {

        // if not, create it with 755 persmission
        // NB: You need to have enough permissions to perform this action
        if(mkdir($this->dirname, 0755))
        {
            return true;
        }
            //$this->uErrors[] = 'لا تملك الصلاحيات الكافية ﻹنشاء مجلد جديد';
            return false; // in case of not enough permission
    } // end is_dir

        return false;

} // end newDir


/*
# Scanning file from any malware / virus using Clamav (Clam Anti Virus)
# Works with Ubuntu ==> sudo apt-get install clamav
*/
public final function scanFile(){

    //$safe_path = escapeshellarg($this->fileTmp);
    $safe_path = escapeshellarg($this->dirname.'/'.$this->fileName);
    $cmd = '/usr/bin/clamscan  2>&1' . $safe_path;
    $result = $cmd;
    //echo $result.'<br />';
    $out = '';
    $int = -1;
    $return = exec($cmd, $out, $int);

    // if a malware / virus found
    if ($int != 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }   
        return false;

}


// delete file if a virus / malware found
public final function delFile(){

    // if true 
    //if($this->scanFile()){
        /*
        $this->uErrors[] = 'لم نتمكن من رفع الملف، المرجو المحاولة لاحقا';

        // get current URL
        $curURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        // refresh after 5 secs
        //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; '.$curURL.'" />';
        */
        $delFile = unlink($this->fileTmp); // Delete the file
        if($delFile)
        {
            return true;
            //$this->dErrors[] = 'ملف يحتوي على فيروس، تم المسح بنجاح';
        }
            return false;
        //else
        //{
            //$this->dErrors[] = 'ملف يحتوي على فيروس، فشلت عملية المسح';
        //} // end if($delFile)   
    //} // end if($this->scanFile()){
 } // end delFile()



// upload the file
public final function uploadFile($target){

    $this->target = $target;

    if(file_exists($this->target)){
    $moveFile = $this->target.'/'.$this->fileName;
    echo $moveFile.'<br />';

    $upFile = move_uploaded_file($this->fileTmp, $moveFile);

    echo $upFile.'<br />';

    if($upFile) {
        //echo 'تم رفع الملف '.$this->fileName.' بنجاح';
        //$eMsg = 'تم رفع الملف '.$this->fileName.' بنجاح';
        return true;
    }
        //echo 'لم يتم رفع الملف '.$this->fileName.' بنجاح';
        //$eMsg = 'لم يتم رفع الملف '.$this->fileName.' بنجاح';

    }
    else{
        $this->newDir($this->target);
    }
        //$this->eMsg = $eMsg;
} // end uploadFile


// after uploading, for security reason, rename the uploaded file
public final function renameFile($location){

    $this->location = $location;

    // for security reason and better classification, use today date and time
    $todayDate  = date('Y-m-d'); // get today date as a string
    $todayTime  = date('h-i-s'); // get today time as a string
    $now        = time(); // get timestamp

    $this->todayDate    = $todayDate;
    $this->todayTime    = $todayTime;
    $this->now          = $now;

    $renameFrom     = $this->location.'/'.$this->fileName;
    $renameTo       = $this->todayDate.'_'.$todayTime.'_'.$this->now.'.'.$this->fileExt; // i.e: 2013-05-29_08-21-14_1369808474.htm

    $fileDestination = $this->location.'/'.$renameTo;

    $fileNewName            = rename($renameFrom, $fileDestination);

    $this->renameFrom       = $renameFrom;
    $this->renameTo         = $renameTo;
    $this->fileDestination  = $fileDestination;

    // set proper chmod, DO NOT use umask
    chmod($fileDestination, 0644);

} // end renameFile



// filter file
public final function filterFile(){

    // list disable functions, get it from your php.ini
    $disFunctions = array('curl_multi_exec', 'parse_ini_file', 'readfile', 'symlink', 'shell_exec', 'exec', 'proc_close', 'proc_open', 'popen', 'show_source', 'system', 'dl', 'passthru', 'escapeshellarg', 'escapeshellcmd', 'pcntl_alarm', 'pcntl_fork', 'pcntl_waitpid', 'pcntl_wait', 'pcntl_wifexited', 'pcntl_wifstopped', 'pcntl_wifsignaled', 'pcntl_wexitstatus', 'pcntl_wtermsig', 'pcntl_wstopsig', 'pcntl_signal', 'pcntl_signal_dispatch', 'pcntl_get_last_error', 'pcntl_strerror', 'pcntl_sigprocmask', 'pcntl_sigwaitinfo', 'pcntl_sigtimedwait', 'pcntl_exec', 'pcntl_getpriority', 'pcntl_setpriority');

    $this->disFunctions = $disFunctions;

    // get file content

    $cFile = file_get_contents($this->fileDestination, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

    foreach($this->disFunctions as $kkeys)
    {
        if(preg_match('#'.$kkeys.'#i', $cFile))
        {
            $this->aErrors[] = 'ملف يحتوي على دوال خطيرة';
            //echo count($this->aErrors).'<br />';

            //echo 'exists<br />';
            //return false;
        }
    } // end foreach
} // end filterFile


####################### Global Functions Start ###############################
// mail function
public final function mailMsg($from, $to, $subject, $message){

// params
 $sensivity = "Sensitivity: Private\n";
 $priority  = "X-Priority: 1 (Higuest)\n";

 $this->from        = $from;
 $this->to          = $to;
 $this->subject     = $subject;
 $this->message     = $message;
 $this->sensivity   = $sensivity;
 $this->priority    = $priority;

 // headers
 $headers = "From:=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($this->subject)."?=<'.$this->from.'>\r\n";
 $headers .= $this->sensivity;
 $headers .= $this->priority;

 $this->headers = $headers;


 mail($this->to, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->headers);
} // end mailMsg()
// mail function end


// getIP function
public final function chkip() {
$ip = "";
$proxy = "";
if (isset($_SERVER)) {
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        $proxy = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
} else {
    if ( getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' ) ) {
        $ip = getenv( 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        $proxy = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    } elseif ( getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' ) ) {
        $ip = getenv( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP' );
    } else {
        $ip = getenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
    }
}
if (strstr($ip, ',')) {
    $ips = explode(',', $ip);
    $ip = $ips[0];
}
if ($proxy != '') {
    $ip = $ip . '(Proxy: '.$proxy.')';
}
return $ip;
}
################# Global Functions EnD #####################

public final function banIPTables() {

    $this->getIP = $this->chkip();

    $cmd = '/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s '.$this->getIP.' -j DROP';
    //echo $cmd.'<br />';
    $run = exec($cmd .' 2>&1');
    echo 'run '.$run.'<br />';

} // end banIPTables


public final function banDB($tableName, $fieldName) {

    $this->getIP      = $this->chkip();
    $this->tableName  = $tableName;
    $this->fieldName  = $fieldName;

    /*
    // assuming connection to host and db are already done
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->tableName.' VAlUES ('.$this->fieldName.');';
    // you should proceed the query later, depends on you :)
    $this->sql = $sql;

    $query = $connexion->query($sql); 
    */

} // end banIPTables


// get uErrors
public final function getError(){

    //http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
    switch($this->fileError)
    {
    case 1: // Server side (php.ini)
    case 2: // Form side (MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    $this->uErrors[] = 'الملف كبير الحجم';
    break;

    case 3:
    $this->uErrors[] = 'لم يتم رفع الملف كاملا';
    break;

    case 4:
    $this->uErrors[] = 'المرجو إختيار ملف لرفعه';
    break;

    case 6:
    $this->uErrors[] = 'لا يوجد مجلد مؤقت بالسيرفر';
    break;

    case 7:
    $this->uErrors[] = 'لا يمكن رفع الملف على السيرفر';
    break;

    default:
    $this->uErrors[] = 'خطأ غير معروف';
    break; 
    } // end switch        
} // end getError()

// check if any uErrors
public final function checkErrors(){

    $countuErrors = count($this->uErrors);

    if((IsSet($this->uErrors) && (is_array($this->uErrors) && ($countuErrors > 0))))
    {
        return true;            
    }
        return false;
} // end checkErrors()


// print user errors
public final function printErrors(){

    $countuErrors = count($this->uErrors);

    if((IsSet($this->uErrors) && (is_array($this->uErrors) && ($countuErrors > 0))))
    {
        //echo $this->eMsg;
        echo 'لم يتم رفع الملف '.$this->fileName.' بنجاح';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($this->uErrors as $uV)
        {       
            echo '<li>';
            echo $uV;
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }                
} // end printErrors()


// mail dangerous errors to the admin
public final function mailErrors(){

    $countaErrors = count($this->aErrors);

    if((IsSet($this->aErrors) && (is_array($this->aErrors) && ($countaErrors > 0))))
    {
        // extract errors
        /*
        foreach($this->aErrors as $aV)
        {       
            echo '<li>';
            echo $aV;
            echo '</li>';
        }
        */

        echo 'mail it<br />';
        echo 'transfert to qurantine';
    }                
} // end printErrors()






} // end class

############## USAGE Start ################

$fileField  = 'fileName';
$sendName   = 'Send';

$maxUpSize      = 200000; // max file size: 2KB
$authExt        = array('png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'docx', 'htm', 'ogv'); // authorized files
$authExtList    = implode(' ،',$authExt);
$current_url    = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$target         = 'Images';

if(IsSet($_POST[$sendName]))  {  

// initialize the class
$up = new uploadFiles($fileField);

// check if file uploads is set to ON (1) OR OFF(0) => active or not
if($up->checkUploads()){

//$up->getFileInfo(); // get file information (size, temp name,..)
$up->allowedFileExt($authExt); // list authorized files
$up->allowedFileSize($maxUpSize); // Input max file size

//$up->checkDir('/home/aburayane/www/Images');
$up->newDir('Images');

//echo 'del '.$up->delFile();

//if($up->scanFile()) { // scan file: malware / virus found
    // actions: what to do
    //$up->banIPTables(); // ban throw IPTables
    /*
    $up->banDB('banIPs', 'ip'); // ban into DB


    if($up->delFile()){ // id deleted
    $eMsg = 'ملف يحتوي على فيروس، تم المسح بنجاح';
    } else {
    $eMsg = 'ملف يحتوي على فيروس، فشلت عملية المسح';
    $up->renameFile('Qurantine'); // move the suspecious file to quarantine
    }
    $up->mailMsg('Guard', 'aburayane@gmail.com', 'Virus / Malware Found', $eMsg); // mail admin
    */
//}

if($up->checkErrors() === TRUE)
{
   $up->getError(); // get uErrors 
   $up->printErrors(); // print uErrors 
}
else
{
    $up->uploadFile($target); // upload
    //$up->scanFile();
    $location = 'Images';
    $up->renameFile($location); // rename
    //$up->filterFile(); // filter file

    $up->mailErrors(); // print all uErrors 
    //$up->printErrors(); // get uErrors 

} // end if($up->checkErrors() === TRUE)


} else {
echo 'عملية رفع الملفات غير مفعلة في السيرفر<br />';
} // end if($up->checkUploads()){

} // end if(IsSet($_POST['Send'])) {


################# USAGE EnD #######################
?>

<fieldset style="width: 700px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; border-width: 0px;">

<form name="formUp" method="POST" action="<?php echo $current_url; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $maxUpSize; ?>" />

<ul>
<li style="list-style: none;">
<label for="file" style="width: 130px; display: inline; float: right; margin-right: 1em; font-weight: bold;">إختر الملف المناسب</label>
<input type="file" name="<?php echo $fileField; ?>" class="fileName" />
</li>

<li style="list-style: none;">
<span style="margin-right: 2em;">
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $sendName; ?>" class="submitFile" value="باسم الله" />
</span>
<span>حجم الملف لا يتعدى 200 كيلو بايت</span>
<br />
الإمتدادات المقبولة: <span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $authExtList; ?>.</span>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
</fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your usual support

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are doing with the file. Suggestion: never provide direct link to the uploaded file. also generate a new safe name for the file to store if filesystem. keep the original name linked somewhere like a database.

Comment: This a fileUpload class, I am just checking if there is a code or part code that is missing for file uploading

Comment: There are some people who are making some malicious programs in an image, and upload as it is an image

Answer (score 0):

With finfo functions you can check the mime/type and allow just a few mime/types like image/jpeg, text/plain etc. To use such functions you need to have fileinfo extension in your phpinfo.
Be aware that it does not return accurate data on $_FILES or temp files, better to save file physically first, if mime is invalid then delete the file. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

And for a list of mimetypes see https://gist.github.com/nimasdj/801b0b1a50112ea6a997